# Modal pop up while page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My intention was to make a modal pop up window when I click a button which links me to another aspx page while it loads. I have the following codes:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function showLoading() {
         $find('mpbLoading').show();
         $find('mpbLoading')._layout();
     }
     function hideLoading() {
         $.find('mpbLoading').hide();
         $.find('mpbLoading')._layout();
     }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnClientClick="showLoading()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Content>
```

There are also cs files which defines the show and hide function. But when i run the website it gives an exception:

JavaScript runtime error: unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference, and highlights 
    $find('mpbLoading').show();

What did I do wrong? What are the methods I can use to accomplish the modal pop up? I was able to trace the problem to MicrosoftAjax.js. and it always returns null.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `mpbLoading`? an id, a class, a node-name?

Comment: oh sorry. it is defined like this:  protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender mpeLoading;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$find('mpbLoading').show();` use `$.find('mpbLoading').show();`

Comment: I tried that. but instead of giving me the null reference error, it just says $ is undefined?

Comment: Then you probably don't have jquery referenced, or it is referenced in wrong place.

Comment: I referenced jquery like this: src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js. And then it gives the error saying showLoading is not defined. But i clearly defined it?

Comment: <a onclick="showLoading();" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">LinkButton</a>       

When i ran my website it highlights this line, which is in the aspx page and says showLoading is undefined. But when i stop the debugger all these codes are gone.